# Is there a good alternative to SPUtility.ResolvePrincipal for claims?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, claims-based-auth, user-accounts

Is there a good alternative to `SPUtility.ResolvePrincipal` for claims?

I have a situation where I have users' email addresses, and I need to get their login names so I can call `SPWeb.EnsureUser`.  Since switching to claims, `ResolvePrincipal` only works if the people have already been added to the site users list, and I need it to specifically work if they have *not* already been added there, because the whole point is to call `EnsureUser` to make sure anyone who has not been added yet is added.

I found a [blog post](http://kjellsj.blogspot.com/2012/02/sharepoint-resolveprincipal-for-adfs.html) that shows how to make a claim-like string using `SPClaimProviderManager.CreateUserClaim`, but if I use their email address in that, it creates a claim like `i:0e.t|issuer|dylan.cristy@company.com` which fails on `EnsureUser` because our real claims are more like `i:0e.t|issuer|dcristy@domain.company.com`.

I've found that I can call `EnsureUser` with the email address and not the login name, but then it creates a user account with the login/claim like `c:05.t|issuer|email.address@company.com` which ends up not actually matching people's real accounts.

How can I get the correct, proper claim to use in `EnsureUser` if all I have to work with is an email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally figure out a good workaround.  Keep in mind my end goal is to be able to identify users (using only their email address) that have *not* been added to a site yet, so that I can call `EnsureUser` and ensure that they *are* then added to the site.

Since in my case `SPUtility.ResolvePrincipal` got cut off from its access to AD, I had to reach out to AD directly through the `System.DisrectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace.  Then once I have the user principal from AD, I have to construct a correctly formatted claim based on the user's UPN to be able to pass that to `EnsureUser`.

```
// in addition to other usings, you definitely need these...

using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

SPUser spUser = null;
SPPrincipalInfo spUserPrincipal = null;

spUserPrincipal = SPUtility.ResolvePrincipal(elevatedWeb, email, SPPrincipalType.User, SPPrincipalSource.All, null, true);

if (spUserPrincipal != null)
{
    // EnsureUser is a bit redundant here because ResolvePrincipal will only have worked if
    // the user is already added to the site users list, but in the end
    // i need an SPUser object, so might as well...

    spUser = elevatedWeb.EnsureUser(spUserPrincipal.LoginName);
}
else
{
    // ResolvePrincipal didn't work, so we know we need to grab the user directly from AD

    string samlClaim = null;

    using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAINNAME"))
    {
        // set up a user principal with parameters to search by,
        // namely, email address.  making sure it's enabled is also
        // probably a good thing to check for

        UserPrincipal searchPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
        searchPrincipal.EmailAddress = email;
        searchPrincipal.Enabled = true;

        PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(searchPrincipal);
        Principal adPrincipal = searcher.FindOne();
        if (adPrincipal != null)
        {
            SPClaimProviderDefinition claimProviderDef = SPClaimProviderManager.Local.GetClaimProvider("LDAPCP");
            string issuerIdentifier = claimProviderDef.ClaimProvider.GetLocalizedDisplayName();

            // build the claim token / string to use later

            samlClaim = SPClaimProviderManager.CreateUserClaim(adPrincipal.UserPrincipalName, SPOriginalIssuerType.TrustedProvider, issuerIdentifier).ToEncodedString().ToLower();
        }
        else
        {
            // didn't find an account in AD with the specified email (at least, not one that's active)
        }
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(samlClaim))
    {
        // call EnsureUser with the correctly constructed claim
        // to then add the user to the site

        spUser = elevatedWeb.EnsureUser(samlClaim);
    }
    else
    {
        // must not have found the user account based on email, so therefore
        // couldn't construct the claim, and with no claim, can't call EnsureUser
    }
}
```